# Is it correct to use a tag inside figure tag?

Tags: html

I attend to put a link on an image, who can help me? Is it correct to use a tag inside a figure tag?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.13.8/resources/dojo.min.css" />

<figure class="mar-btm-30">
  <a href="" alt="">
    <img class="img-responsive image-center" title="" alt="" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png" />
    <figcaption class="text-center"><em>Caption</em></figcaption>
  </a>
</figure>
```

Comment: I made you a snippet. It looks like you are using DOJO so I added the stylesheet to it too. Please use placeholder.com or similar if you have images in your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need the alt attribute in the a tag but all in all your solution is right. You just need to wrap yor img tag with an a tag.